# Call an event from another element

Tags: javascript

I have `button A` with

```
onclick = "alert(1);"
```

And `button B`.

How to do, when I click on `button B` , it should call event on `button A` ?

click B -> eventB -> eventA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML:

```
<button id="buttonA"> Button A </button>
<button id="buttonB"> Button B </button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var a = g('buttonA'),
    b = g('buttonB');

function g(s) { return document.getElementById(s); }

a.onclick = function() {
    alert('Button A clicked!');
};

b.onclick = function() {
    alert('Button B clicked!');
    a.click();
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/TaPWr/1/

---

**Update:**

If the Button B is inside an IFRAME then use the `top` object to reference the window object of the "parent" page. The IFRAME code would be like so:

```
var b = document.getElementById('buttonB');

b.onclick = function() {
    alert('Button B clicked!');
    top.document.getElementById('buttonA').click();
}
```

Comment: if Button B is in a iframe and button A is out of iframe ? how

Comment: @Chameron Do both pages comply with the Same Origin Policy? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: @Chameron Use `top` to get the parent window. See my updated answer.

Comment: I have a question, what's the difference between `top` and `parent`?

Comment: @JCOC *"Where the window.parent property returns the immediate parent of the current window, window.top returns the topmost window in the hierarchy of window objects."* from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.top

Answer (score 1):

```
onclick="document.getElementById('buttonAId').click();"
```

put that on button B

update: if button A is in the form that has iframe where button A is:

```
onclick="parent.document.getElementById('buttonAId').click();"
```

assuming both frames are served from the same domain

Comment: if Button B is in a iframe and button A is out of iframe ? how ?

Comment: same way, just use the respective DOMs (document objects), however if the iframes are server from different domains you will not be able to do it in most up to date browsers